# Similarity between Atmega162 and Arduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr, atmega

I am going to be taking an embedded systems course where we will be using the Atmega162 and I want to get started learning the stuff before the course begins.Now my question is, considering that there are many good resources for the Arduino and relatively scarce resources for the Atmega162, and that the Arduino is a lot less intimidating than the Atmega162, would it be beneficially if I just learned the Arduino and then used some of that knowledge on the 162?, or do the two microcontrollers have significant differences that would make using this strategy inefficient? Plus I already have access to an Arduino Uno but I probably won't get access to an actual Atmega162 until I start the course.

Comment: If you intend to learn to program MCU professionally advise you not to settle on a board with abstraction code  as arduino, and with a little study, you will notice that a lot of sample code on other architectures as: Z8, RS08, STM7, PSoC1, etc can serve to  learn programming your AVR8. however if you use a code friedly, will be unable to obtain useful when moving from one architecture to another.

Comment: Valid point for professional engineers but if it's a helpful stepping stone for you (many of us learn differently), then have at it.

Comment: It is certainly possible to bypass the Arduino IDE and program the Arduino board directly in Ada or C if you prefer.

Comment: @Brian Drummond Do you have any resources mentioning how to get into Ada programming on AVR?

Comment: I use the AVR-Ada project from Sourceforge, [https://sourceforge.net/projects/avr-ada/]. I am working on something similar for the MSP430. Getting started is not trivial; currently you first have to build the compiler (there is a script that ought to do it). The project's Wiki page has some good examples. For a GPL edition of a commercial Gnat release there is also [http://libre.adacore.com/download/] where you can select "avr-elf-windows" at the "Select your platform" step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Arduino Uno has an Atmel ATmega328 onboard out of the box, but it can be replaced by a 168, and a couple others if memory serves me. Moral of the story is all Arduino boards use Atmel microcontrollers. The architecture of the AVR line is almost identical from chip to chip, down to the register content is some cases. The thing that makes Arduino easy for the hobbyists and newbies is the software.

You're going to learn how to program micros like a professional in your class. In industry, that Arduino pseudo-code is useless. I wouldn't bother with Arduino unless you have some hobby project where you need a micro, and don't want to think about it much.

Comment: I've read similar statements made by professionals. I suppose it's similar to admitting using RealBasic in the presence of established software engineers. :-) I'm happy to step outside my comfort zone and admit blissful ignorance (and burned out micros) but I think, like RealBasic and other training wheel platforms, it's a great stepping stone for those without formal education.

Comment: Adding: Head over to ebay and buy yourself a small lot of ATMEGA328 chips for cheap (shipping from China takes awhile but I haven't seen better prices anywhere else). That way, if you do burn out your Arduino's brain you can flash the bootloader onto a new chip and slap it into your board in a few minutes. I haven't burned a chip yet but I'm sure I will sooner or later.

Comment: @RTOSkit Let's keep perspective in mind. We don't all necessarily share the same goals. For my purposes (as I'm primarily a software engineer who discovered he loves to tinker with electronics), Arduino is the PERFECT stepping stone for hitting the ground running on a first-time project. There's perspective ("your platform is entry-level") and then there's elitism ("you're wasting your time because you're not close enough to bare-metal"). I've been impressed with how friendly this community usually is toward hobbyists. More of that, please.

Comment: So it is possible to program the Atmega328 on the Uno without using the Arduino IDE? Apart from avrfreaks, is there any other site that has resources that could help me?

Comment: I'm just getting started, but I believe the (clunky on OS X) GUI just calls the command line stuff (I think `avrdude`). The .ino files it produces are plain text. I'm sure you could edit it with vim and run avrdude manually. Once you have your firmware finalized, you can flash the chip with that code on its own, without the Arduino bootloader (to avoid the startup delay and memory usage). Again, I'm just getting started with the platform but this is what I've read from http://arduino.cc

Comment: Strangely, ATMEGA chips go for twice the price when preloaded with the Arduino boot loader. No sucker am I, so I bought a few blanks (in case I damage anything) and have the arduino.cc tutorial for turning the board into a temporary programmer. Alternatively, you can by Amtel's programmer for ~$35.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi I understand your position, but I think the user show his intention of learning to program MCU. Use shortcuts to learn something well, it's not the right way to start, not matter if something is simple or complex, and surely if someone is good at hardware programming, whether he use an arduino board or use a xmos board. I feel for them to advise him not to waste time and focus their study on something more reusable. PS. I think none of this community here has answered so unfriendly.

Comment: Except that this is exactly how I went from newbie to senior software engineer with no schooling: I dove in at an easy entry point and delved into the lower level stuff as I went. I see nothing wrong with *adding* to his knowledge with a fairly popular entry level platform. Learning something new is never a waste of time, no matter what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi I think you need to see what's going on under the hood of your Arduino to understand why professionals have this opinion. The Arduino firmware severely limits the micro. Those handy functions like digital_read and whatever others there are exactly that, functions. The user is constrained by the firmware. I worked with a group trying to build a robot and the micro guy used the board with the 2560. We had nothing but timing issues and ended up wiping the bootloader and programming it with our own software, and it starting working almost 100% immediately.

Comment: The reason I am against Arduino as a learning platform is the simple fact that ignorance of crucial topics such as bit masking, and control registers is acceptable, and almost encouraged. The user doesn't even have to set the ports up, and it just works. These are things that every embedded system developer needs to learn, whether they be developing AVR, PIC, ARM, or any flavor of DSP.

Comment: @MattYoung - What are you talking about? You can do bit-masking, twiddle control registers, mess around with the integrated peripherals and more with an arduino.

Comment: Personally, I have a designed a number of projects at work that use various AVR MCUs, and I still like the arduino for little hobby projects just because it lets you ignore a lot of the obnoxious crap that it takes to get, for example, `printf` working on a new board within Atmel studio.

Comment: Really, you can use an arduino **just** for the bootloader and ease-of-programming, and not have to use **any** other component of the system. Stuff like the `DigitalRead`, `DigitalWrite` and other functions are *completely optional*.

Comment: Furthermore, there is no "Arduino Firmware". There is the Arduino Bootloader, which is *just* a bootloader, and there is the arduino toolchain, which certainly does do some obnoxious things, but you don't need to use the arduino toolchain with the arduino bootloader. AVRdude supports writing to arduinos, so you could easily use plain-old gcc with an arduino that way.

Comment: @MattYoung - If you had someone having timing issues with an Arduino Mega, it means he probably forgot to turn off the interrupt the Arduino toolchain enables by default. You can [easily turn](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Timer-Interrupts/) all the arduino [default stuff off](https://billgrundmann.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/the-overhead-of-arduino-interrupts/).

Comment: @FakeName - that's not entirely accurate.  Arduino is not really a toolchain (it uses gcc and avrdude), rather it is a collection of libraries which typically become major components of the end firmware, a bootloader, some scripts to drive the toolchain, an IDE, and a bunch of documentation/examples/support.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Point taken. I tend to think of all the software on the computer-end that takes C files and outputs hex files/programs a device as the "toolchain".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something more closely approximating the class, you can install the Arduino software to test the board, then learn how to use avr-gcc and avrdude to compile and load bare-metal projects where you write all of the code, rather than using the Arduino library functions.

The difference between the two chips will be of quite limited relevance, though it could be educational to compare the data sheets and make a list of the differences that you do find.

However, there's a fairly high chance that your course will not use avr-gcc, but some other compiler and likely some other programming tool.  Also, there will probably be a different coding style and perhaps some macros for chip registers different than whatever you settle upon on your won.  So you will likely still end up with some transition - but of a sort that is useful to contemplate, as learning to translate between those environment issues will give you more flexibility in the future.  For example, you might want to leverage app-note code that assumes a different compiler than what you end up using on a project.  Or you might be working on a project for some time, decide various limitations of the toolchain you have been using are no longer tolerable, and want to move the project to a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a late answer, but it may be of interest to someone else stumbling upon this. While it is true that currently, Arduino is a language at to high a level to truly be useful professionally, even though there certainly are products from smaller companies reaching market today with some Arduino based parts in them. However, I think this may change:

I am more at home in software engineering than embedded and electronics design with some 20 years of professional experience in the former. I started learning programming back on my C64, but rather soon got into C and later also C++ since those where the standard languages back then which you really had to be proficient in. 1995 Java came around and I was an early adaptor. Most people were pretty skeptical though, a managed language with Garbage Collection and that high level of abstraction surely was nothing more than a teaching tool or something you could build a simple UI in or something, for real applications you still needed C++. Well today Java and C# (which is very much at the same level of abstraction) are easily the most dominant languages, especially when it comes to enterprise applications. Yes, there are still places where C++ is used, games being an obvious one, but that's just something like at most 5% of all code being written today.

Why is this? Well technological advances happen quickly in this field and they can be used for basically four things: Making hardware cheaper, making it smaller, making it faster or enabling it to perform tasks earlier not possible. In computers, both PC's and Servers, smaller isn't really an issue, the limiting factor in making a laptop smaller are batteries and the fact that you can't have to small a screen. New tasks, well there's not really any demand for that unless it's something spectacular. So hardware became faster and cheaper. At the same time, the demand for programmers are steadily increasing meaning they get more and more expensive, leading to the simple fact in computer software development today: Programmer hours are more expensive than RAM and CPU cycles, thus you wan't languages and frameworks that are not necessarily simple, but that takes care of "boilerplate" things like memory management, communication protocols, data access etc, letting the programmers focus on the things that can't really be solved by throwing hardware on them.

Now for embedded things are slightly, but not massively different, mainly in two factors: Size was still an issue, and still is in some applications and Embedded systems are often parts of appliances and therefor not readily upgradable or changed, can't take advantage of other units on a network to unload work etc. What they are when built is what they will stay and they have to be self sufficient. This last part is changing as different communication stacks are getting more available for embedded systems. However, these differences are not fundamental, they only make the same development be later in happening and not as quickly in taking effect as in computer software. We are getting to a point where you can get the computing power of an average gaming PC 10 years ago for 8 bucks at the size of a credit card, including connection peripherals and even WiFi - likely within not a long time at all we will be at a point where the same is true for embedded as it is for computer software: engineering hours are more expensive than hardware, meaning it will make more and more sense to use higher levels of abstraction. Given the choice of making an Atmel chip twice as fast or twice as small at the same cost today it would in most cases make more sense to make it faster and spend that performance on making the life of the programmer easier.

Not, I'm not saying Arduino is the future of embedded development, I think it has numerous flaws that will disqualify it from that. I do however believe that some more high level language will manifest itself pretty soon and it will be a huge change to the industry.

Cheers